# Makefile: Is it possible to create target that runs some tool with options/flags passed via command line

Tags: makefile

I am using Makefile as an automation tool. Let assume that I have some CLI tool and I can call it like this:

```
mytool --arg1=X --flag
```

Options like `--arg1` and `--flag` could be optional, and values for `--arg1` may vary.

I want to write the following target in the Makefile:

```
tool:
    mytool $@
```

Usage:

```
make tool --arg1=Y
```

`$@` doesn't work in this case, I am also trying to do some magic with `$MAKECMDGOALS` but it totally ignores options/flags. Is there any possibility to achieve my goal?

Comment: How about `make tool flags='--arg1=Y'`?

Comment: What @HolyBlackCat suggests is that you call `maytool $(flags) $@` instead of `maytool $@`, and you pass the value of the `flags` make variable on the command line with `make tool flags='--arg1=X --flag'`.

Comment: `make tool flags='--arg1=Y'` is a viable solution, but more verbose than my usage example, you should always keep in mind, that you should use it with this "special wrapper". My goal is to provide an intuitive UX for other developers on the project.

Comment: So why not `make tool arg1=Y` and then `mytool --arg1=$(arg1) $@` in your Makefile? What UI would you prefer? Remember that any `--option` that you pass on the command line will be considered as a make option. So you cannot decide that `--arg1` shall be recognized by make as a valid option (unless you modify the source code of make, of course).

Comment: Then consider writing a wrapper shell script that translates `make tool --foo --bar` into `make tool flags='--foo --bar'`.

Comment: But make accepts variables overriding on the command line with the `make GOAL VAR1=VALUE1 VAR2=VALUE2...` syntax. See for instance [the GNU make documentations](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding). This should allow you to define a user-friendly interface for the other developers.

Comment: Both your suggestions are very interesting. My goal was to achieve nearly the same experience as with any CLI tool, but I think I should use `make tool arg1=Y`. It will provide some complexity to the Makefile target implementation, because I also have short options, need to deal with optional flags, but I can handle it.

Comment: Thank you all for this conversation and great ideas.

Comment: To sum up: the options on the command line for `make` are parsed by `make` and must be valid `make` options, as shown by the documentation.  It's not possible to give arbitrary options to `make` and have it ignore those options, so that makefiles can try to do something special with them.

Comment: @MadScientist, thank you for summarizing the conversation above. I wanted to make sure that I have no possibilities to use arbitrary options with make. Now it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Makefile:

```
tool:
    mytool $(mytool_args)
```

Usage:

```
make tool mytool_args="--arg1=Y --flag"
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a viable solution, and finally, I will land with it. But I wanted to pass arbitrary options (including flags) to the make target. Looks like it is impossible.

Comment: yes, there is no such thing as "options to the target" in `GNU make`. From the command line you can only supply the list of targets to make and override variables, that's all.